# easy way to highlight ios text box when it has focus?

Tags: ios, textbox, uitextfield, ios6

Our iOS6 app is data-entry-heavy and has small fonts, and we want to make it easier for users to find the currently focused field among many fields on the screen.

First, I notice that iOS by default doesn't do anything to draw the user's eye to a focused text field, unlike many other platforms and apps. Is this because it's an explicit design guideline or implicit app-store requirement that text fields should *not* display a focus highlight?  I don't want to get our app ejected from the app store for this minor thing. ;-)

Assuming focus highlighting is allowed, is there an easy way to show a "glow" inside or outside the text box when it gets focus, like I can do with CSS on a web app using `box-shadow`, as in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYZWt/1/).

Finally, do you know good examples of iOS apps that have done what we're trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it's prohibited to do that. Although I think Apple would recommend if it's necessary to mark the selected textfield, you should consider splitting your view into multiple screens. A single screen shouldn't get too cluttered.

However if in your case that's not possible or not wanted, the easiest way to achieve a 'glow-effect' would be this (modify the values as you see fit):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

textField.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
textField.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
textField.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
```

(Don't forget to add the Quarz Framework to your project)

It would look like this:
[image]

Comment: great response, just what I was looking for. If we want to put the glow on the inside instead of the outside, is that straightforward too?

Comment: No that would be more complicated. The `UITextField` is build of many different views. Off the top of my head I would try to add another subview to it - maybe a bit smaller than the textfield - set its background color to clear, set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` and add the shadow as described above. But I haven't tried that, so no warranty that it won't mess up the textfield ;)